# Open a Finder window for another user account

Tags: macos, finder

I'm switching between a couple of different user-accounts on my mac at the moment.

I regularly want a file that's in another other user account and most of the time I can get it by scp'ing from the current account, but sometimes I want a GUI.  Is there a way that I can open a finder window that views another user-accounts files?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't bring your permissions to the files in question so you could open them as part of a group? Heck, you could add yourself to the group - do the things you want, then take yourself out of the group if you didn't always want access. Seems easier than bringing their permissions to your finder UI.

Comment: @bmike Interesting...  The honest answer about permissions is that I don't generally know which files are necessarily in advance... but you might be suggesting, effectively 'share your whole drive with the group', which sort of solves the problem... I kind of want to be able to do everything from the client account tho...

Comment: Totally - do you know both passwords, and is one account admin and the OS Mojave or recent?

Comment: @bmike I have All The Passwords, Current version osx, and one is account admin.